# On-the-fly modifications of the links according to a set of rules (Greasekit / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, greasekit, fluid-mac-app-engine

I have an HTML page with loads of entries like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/product?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=123456789&amp;tab=UK_Default" class="PrmryBtnMed"
```

I want to replace all this links so they instead are:

```
https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=1233456789
```

So, it's quite a complicated search and replace. These are the instructions for a human:

1. Look at the URL. Only make a note of the number after 'asin='. (Forget everything before that and everything after that)
2. Then, form a new URL, using this ASIN. It will ALWAYS start like this:
   `https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=`

With the number stuck on the end to form:

```
https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=123456789
```

Kindly note

- rather than modifying the existing buttons, it would also be acceptable to add a new button [or link] near the original buttons
- both the original and new links point to the same domain
- I'm using Greasekit on a SSB called FluidApp, but I can switch to Greasemonkey on FireFox.

I've just watched 40 JavaScript tutorial videos - man this language is hard! This seems extremely difficult. I would hugely appreciate any help/pointers.

Comment: Do you want to do this for every `<a>` on the pages or are there conditions? You say in the title, `according to a set of rules`.

Comment: I want to do this for every button on the page - there are about 11. If it helps, they all have class="PrmryBtnMed". Furthermore, they all say <span>Send me this item</span>. So, the set of rules, or rule, would be to look for these buttons!

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Ideally, I would like it to apply on every link on the page that contains `asin`. (Please disregard the stuff about the primary button, earlier). Is this possible to achieve programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
// the new base url
var base = ' https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
// all the links with className 'PrmryBtnMed'
var links  = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
    // check each link for the 'asin' value
    var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(links[i].getAttribute('href'));
    if(result){
        // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
        links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/L8ePL/

Comment: **Thank you, wonderful person**! we are off to a running start, but there are two problems. (I shall post the two problems as **separate comments** to make it more readable)

Comment: **Problem 1**
It only seems to modify **one button** on the page - the first one. Huh, maybe we should try a new way of finding the buttons? We could approach this from a fresh angle:  How about looking for buttons that have the link `<span>Send me this item</span></a>` (instead of looking by the class `PrmryBtnMed`). Come to think of it, _even better_ would be to modify _every_ link on the page, perhaps narrowing it down to only links that contains the text `asin` in it. (If this is feasible, it would also catch regular links and image links on the page, which would be icing on the cake)

Comment: **problem 2 - the link has some extra characters in it:**

    `https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=123456789`
    
    It should display as :
    
    `http://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=123456789`
    
    In other words, it says `&amp` when I only want it to say `&`

Comment: Ok I've updated the demo to look for every link and not just the ones with the class name `PrmryBtnMed`. Also I've removed the `&amp;`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, **problem 2 is solved** - hooray! (Thank you so much!) However, problem 1 still remains in that it only works for the **first row of the table**. (It does work on all the links within that row). In other words after `</td>` it stops working.

Comment: It should work. If you give me the address of the site you're working on I could help further.

Comment: The site is password protected,perhaps I should mirror the HTML on another site. I'll just get some hosting and do that. :)

Comment: This is the URL of the site: http://albany.net23.net/newsletter.html  (as the actual site is password protected etc, i've mirrored it)

Comment: ok updated. Problem was that the values of `asin` are a mix of numbers and letters and not just numbers as in your example :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, sometimes, it's a mix of letters and numbers. More examples of the `asin` are `B006MOS60Y` and `B003EM8008`.  Did you update the code? (it says last edited on 19 April...)

Comment: Updated. I've tested it on your site and it worked for me. Let me know if it works and if it does, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: it's perfect; you are a gentleman and a scholar. Answer accepted, with thanks. ( I shall also give you upvotes as soon as I am able to.)

Comment: Ha ha glad we got there in the end.

Comment: Oh, is there a tweak I can make so that link opens **in a new window**, when clicked? [if not, I can just right-click]

Comment: Hey man, I seem to be locked out of yahoo mail. I keep getting locket out, for 12 hours at a time. (I set a security question back in 2010, it asked me for it out of the blue). Hopefully, I'll be back in within a few days.