# How can I refine this Javascript code to refine it so it only work on links from images (and NOT links from text)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, getelementsbytagname, greasekit, fluid-mac-app-engine

I want to make some refinement to [some code from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079410/on-the-fly-modifications-of-the-links-according-to-a-set-of-rules-greasekit-j):

```
// the new base url
var base = ' https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
var links  = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
    // check each link for the 'asin' value
    var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(links[i].getAttribute('href'));
    if(result){
        // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
        links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
    }
}
```

Now, **instead** of it acting on **all** links, can I get it to only look at links that are from images?

Here is an HTML snippet to show what I mean:

```
<a href="/shop/product?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=Z00FDLN878&amp;tab=UK_Default" target="_blank"><img width="125" height="125" border="0" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/01W9a7gwosL.jpg" alt="43453"></a>
```

That's an image link - I do want it to act on that.

## Impossible?

My gut instinct is that this isn't actually possible in code - because `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` can't see the difference between a text link and an image link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to pre-select only the right kinds of nodes.  EG:

```
// the new base url
var base        = 'https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
var linkImgs    = document.querySelectorAll ("a > img");

for (var J = linkImgs.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var imgLink = linkImgs[J].parentNode;

    //--- Check each link for the 'asin' value
    var result  = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec (imgLink.getAttribute ('href') );
    if( result) {
        // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
        imgLink.setAttribute ('href', base+result[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: **This is amazing - thank you**. Just out of curiosity, how can I make it the **inverse**? (In other words, so that it only applies the code to text links and not image links). I wonder if I can just put a `!` somewhere ...

Comment: Alas, it's not that easy since CSS does not have a `has` selector. It's easy with jQuery though. You would use `$("a:not(:has(img))")`.

Comment: How, exactly, would I use that, please ? (Perhaps I should make a new question)

Comment: Yes, please make a new question for the new requirement.  It's not hard, but it's a bit much to answer in comments.

Comment: Thanks Brock, I've created it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619331/how-can-i-refine-this-javascript-code-so-it-ignores-links-from-images

Comment: If `document.querySelectorAll ("a > img")` finds the links that are image links, can I use `document.querySelectorAll ("a < img")` to find the inverse ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to check for the link inside the HTML of the link:

```
for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++) {

    // check each link for the 'asin' value
    var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(links[i].getAttribute('href'));

    // check each link for an img tag
    var hasimage = /<img [^>]+>/.test(links[i].innerHTML);

    if(result && hasimage){
        // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
        links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
    }

}
```

Also, using regular expressions to search for HTML probably isn't the best bet, but if you control what's being generated, then this is probably the quickest way without a 3rd party html parser.

Comment: Brian, do you think I could use this technique to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619331/how-can-i-refine-this-javascript-code-so-it-ignores-links-from-images ? (The difference between that question and this, is I now want to **ignore** image links)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the links based on whether or not they contain an image.

```
var links  = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

links = [].filter.call(links, function(item) {
   // test to see if child node is an image
   return item.childNodes[0].nodeName === 'IMG'; 
});

for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
    // do what you gotta do
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the <img> is the first node inside the link.  It very often won't be.  A textnode will usually have that honor.

Answer (score 1):

You can just test for an IMG child and only process the link if there is one there.

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jub45/)

```
// the new base url
var base = ' https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
var links  = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
    var linkElement = links[i];
    //get the first child of the a element
    var firstChild = linkElement.children[0];
    //if there is a child and it's an IMG then process this link
    if (typeof(firstChild) !== "undefined" && firstChild.tagName=="IMG") { 
      // check each link for the 'asin' value
      var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(links[i].getAttribute('href'));
      if(result){
          // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
          links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
      }}
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the <img> is the first node inside the link. It very often won't be. A textnode will usually have that honor.

Comment: @BrockAdams not per OP's example. In fact, I don't agree with that in general. That said it would be simple enough to filter the child nodes as well.

Comment: The OP's example is pared down from a RL site (Amazon UK usually), not as it was found in the wild, and the statement holds.  The first node will be whitespace in many cases. Your answer is what is called "timebomb code".  It's even worse if it *appears* to work, for now.

Comment: @Brock my example isn't production ready :) and I specifically commented that it is only testing the first node. It's intended to note for the OP that it is possible to achieve. Looking at your answer you assume the IMG node is a direct child of an A which I'd guess suffers from the same issue mine has in that we don't know the exact structure of the target elements....

Comment: No, we **do** know the structure and we know that the img **is** a direct child of the `<a>` (assuming that the OP's question is accurate, which it is until proved otherwise).  Whitespace is not structure and OP's condense that all the time because it's not relevant to *smart* code.  Even if the OP pasted in code without any WS changes, RL websites are not consistent or reliable when it comes to WS.  This answer is vulnerable to whitespace and will backfire if it's used - it's just a question of when.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the new base url
var base = ' https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
var links  = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var hrefs = links.parent;

for(var i = 0;i < hrefs.length;i++){
    // check each link for the 'asin' value
    var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(hrefs[i].getAttribute('href'));
    if(result){
        // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
        hrefs[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `links.parent` is going to be?

Comment: `links.parent` should be the `a` element

Comment: Well, `links` is a NodeList. `links[0].parent` might be the `a`, but `links.parent` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [links collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/single-page.html#dom-document-links), and you can can just check if the link has an image child node:

```
var link, links = document.links;
var re = /asin=([\d\w]+)/;
for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  link = links[i]

  if (link.getElementsByTagName('img').length && re.test(link.href)) {
    link.href = base + result[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're checking for a link inside a link.

Answer (score -1):

My initial response would be to look into query Select All and then assign a class name to grab on all of the a tags that would be affected by whatever your trying to do. When I get to my laptop I'll edit this with an example.

Comment: Even if this were a real answer, that sounds overly complicated.

Comment: You add a class to the a elements and call them with queryselectall is overly complicated? I don't get your logic there, it's one of the easiest ways to get a specific element. But since I'll not get a chance anytime soon to defend this with a code example I'll bow out now. Sorry for wasting people's time.

Comment: Well you are talking about selecting all the tags, adding a class, and then reselecting by class. All the other solutions only select once, making your solution needlessly complex.

Comment: If that's what you got from me recommending queryselectall as a potential solution then I must have worded something horribly wrong. I was thinking something more simplistic like select all the a elements then filter out any with an image child and proceed from there. The only reason class was mentioned was to apply it in the html to give a more definitive target for the query,  agreed the class part is not needed however it cuts out alot of fluff to filter through. Wish I was not mobile and could work up a fiddle to show better what I'm talking about.

Comment: Actually just takea look at Brocks answer that is where I was going with this.