# How can I refine this Javascript code so it IGNORES links from images

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, greasekit, fluid-mac-app-engine

## This is a variation of an existing question

{Please note - this question is the opposite/inverse of an [existing StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255051/how-can-i-refine-this-javascript-code-to-refine-it-so-it-only-work-on-links-from) that is [too complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255051/how-can-i-refine-this-javascript-code-to-refine-it-so-it-only-work-on-links-from#comment30482053_20255611) to answer there}

## From the very beginning

I want to make some refinement to [some code from this challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079410/on-the-fly-modifications-of-the-links-according-to-a-set-of-rules-greasekit-j):

```
// the new base url
var base = ' https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
var links  = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0;i < links.length;i++){
    // check each link for the 'asin' value
    var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(links[i].getAttribute('href'));
    if(result){
        // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
        links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
    }
}
```

Now, **instead** of it acting on **all** links, can I get it to only look at links that are from text?

Here is an HTML snippet to show what I mean:

```
<a href="/shop/product?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=Z00FDLN878&amp;tab=UK_Default" target="_blank"><img width="125" height="125" border="0" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/01W9a7gwosL.jpg" alt="43453"></a>
```

That's an image link - I do NOT want it to act on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **straight javascript / DOM**, test the links as you loop through them:

```
var base        = 'https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
var linksNoImg  = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href*='asin']");

for (var J = linksNoImg.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var imgLink = linksNoImg[J];

    //--- Make sure it's not an image link:
    if ( ! imgLink.querySelector ('img') ) {
        //--- Check each link for the 'asin' value
        var result  = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec (imgLink.getAttribute ('href') );
        if (result) {
            // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
            imgLink.setAttribute ('href', base+result[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

**jQuery** lets you preselect only the correct links:

```
//--- The new base URL
var base        = ' https://www.example.co.uk/gp/wine/order?ie=UTF8&asin=';
var linksNoImg  = $("a[href*='asin']:not(:has(img))");

linksNoImg.each ( function () {
    // check each link for the 'asin' value
    var result = /asin=([\d\w]+)/.exec(links[i].getAttribute('href'));
    if(result){
        // make a new url using the 'base' and the 'asin' value
        links[i].setAttribute('href', base+result[1]);
    }
} );
```

But this requires you to load jQuery in Greasekit -- which is well worth it for any but the simplest scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (links[i].querySelector('img')) {
    // Link has an <img>! Oh no!
}
```

To support older browsers, call `getElementsByTagName()` instead (and check for an empty array).

Comment: Can you please give the full code so I can test it? (in the way that Brock Adams has done at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255051/how-can-i-refine-this-javascript-code-to-refine-it-so-it-only-work-on-links-from)

Comment: @Ted: What don't you understand?  Just put that in your loop to skip those elements.

Comment: I have a vague idea of how to proceed but I inevitably misplace a comma or period and break things. Do I put it (`if (links[i].querySelector('img')) {`) in line 4 and add `}` to the end?

Comment: Shall I insert it into line 8? (Sorry if this is a stupid question). Once I've confirmed it has worked I'll gladly accept ("green tick") your answer.

Comment: Ah, I think I finally understand this. If link has an `<img>` then I want it to do nothing, so **can I make it continue with the for loop with no action**?